# AVIF Image File Format Supported by Android 12 not Load in ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-glide, avif, android-12

I have created new Android Application with this settings in build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-S'
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aviftest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion "S"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

I have added Glide Library for Image Loading in ImageView. Code for Loading Image in ImageView is

```
val url:String="https://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2021/02/f1-good-a14c8cc5.avif"
        Glide.with(this).load(url).centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(myImage);
```

The error showing in Log says

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2021/02/f1-good-a14c8cc5.avif with size [198x198]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 root cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

After installing app the Avif Image is not loading from source. What can be the cause for this ?

Comment: Glide supported formats ```GIF, JPEG, RAW, PNG, WEBP.```

Comment: Any different way to display AVIF from drawable or raw folder ?

Comment: convert the file format the use it. check out https://cloudconvert.com/avif-to-jpg

Comment: The main moto is to see the AVIF Image Display in Android 12

Comment: yeah, Im also searching ,if emergency just convert and use it

Answer (score 1):

Glide added AVIF support in [4.13.0](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/tag/v4.13.0) and made it work [4.13.1](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases/tag/v4.13.1).

Next to updating glide, include the [AVIF integration](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/avif.html):

`implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:avif-integration:$glide_version"`